Automatic conversion of false value to array deprecation
I use OpenCart version 3.0.7 and PHP 8.1
I get this error:

Unknown: Automatic conversion of false to array is deprecated in
/home/public/musabgbar/storage/modification/catalog/controller/startup/startup.php
on line 133

After refreshing the page the error disappeared. That happens every time I close the browser and reopen it.
Do know how to modify the code?
    // Language Detection
    if (!empty($this->request->server['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']) && !array_key_exists($code, $languages)) {
        $detect = '';
        
        $browser_languages = explode(',', $this->request->server['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']);
        
        // Try using local to detect the language
        foreach ($browser_languages as $browser_language) {
            foreach ($languages as $key => $value) {
                if ($value['status']) {
                    $locale = explode(',', $value['locale']);
                    
                    if (in_array($browser_language, $locale)) {
                        $detect = $key;
                        break 2;
                    }
                }
            }   
        }           
        if (!$detect && !is_array($languages)) { 
                // Try using language folder to detect the language
                foreach ($browser_languages as $browser_language) {
                    if (array_key_exists(strtolower($browser_language), $languages)) {
                        $detect = strtolower($browser_language);                        
                        break;
                    }
                }
        }
        
        $code = $detect ? $detect : '';
    }
    
    
    if (!array_key_exists($code, $languages)) {
        $code = $this->config->get('config_language');
    }
    
    if (!isset($this->session->data['language']) || $this->session->data['language'] != $code) {
        $this->session->data['language'] = $code ;
    }
            
    if (!isset($this->request->cookie['language']) || $this->request->cookie['language'] != $code) {
        setcookie('language', $code, time() + 60 * 60 * 24 * 30, '/');
    }
            
    // Overwrite the default language object
    $language = new Language($code);
    $language->load($code);
    
    $this->registry->set('language', $language);
    
    // Set the config language_id
    $this->config->set('config_language_id', $languages[$code]['language_id']);         


Since $browser_languages is the only thing that is assumed to be an array, without checking it, I think that must be the culprit. However, the best method to solve this problem is to update OpenCart, or downgrade PHP. They are out of sync. Fiddling with code isn't something you should do unless you really know what you're doing.

$browser_languages has a value of false instead of an array of strings as you expected. So cope with this situation, default it to an empty array, like:
function getBrowserLanguages($browser_languages) {
    return is_array($browser_languages) ? $browser_languages : [];
}

and use this reusable function (possibly embed a caching mechanism too, which I omitted here for the sake of simplicity) in your loop
        if (!$detect && !is_array($languages)) { 
                // Try using language folder to detect the language
                foreach (getBrowserLanguages($browser_languages) as $browser_language) {
                    if (array_key_exists(strtolower($browser_language), $languages)) {
                        $detect = strtolower($browser_language);                        
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

Sure-enough, in this case your loop won't be executed, so you either figure out why it was false in the first place and fix that too, or default this to something like ['en', 'fr', 'hu'].

Oke, yes, you can solve this single problem this way. However, it is somewhat likely that musab will complain that another error has popped up. Without testing the full code you can't be certain this solved the issue.

@KIKOSoftware we can definitely solve this issue. He may have multiple other issues, possibly looking similarly, but if that's the case, he can apply this idea wherever needed, or, even better, have $browser_language defined at exactly one place and defaulted there.

@KIKOSoftware I understand why you dislike it and will change it. But I am sure we need to separate the concern of looping from the concern of defining. Edit will come soon.

@KIKOSoftware my edit was more agnostic. It gets an input, whatever languages are being passed and handles the case when it's not an array.

Oh, a separate function, yes, that's a good idea.

@KIKOSoftware thanks for pointing that out. Edited.
